# How to deleted by row in large data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

> i have a large data frame
>
> the unique(ID)=28560
>
> the unique(code)=10957
>
> dim(table)=1318369 obs 3variable

```
ID    code    N
1     A434    6
1     A314    13
1     477     9
2     A48     2
2     AV69    2
2     53      5
```

and if the code include A then deleted

```
ID    code    N
1     477     9
2     53      5
```

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to subset using first letter (substring):

```
df = subset(df, substr(df$code, 1, 1) != 'A')
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't delete rows in a data frame.  Rather, you select those rows that you want (and if desired, save the result to the same variable).

```
d[-grep('A', d$code),]
##   ID code N
## 3  1  477 9
## 6  2   53 5
```